# Git on top of SVN

Tags: java, eclipse, git, svn, ant

I'm trying to use Eclipse with Git pointing to a SVN directory. (My workplace doesn't trust Git yet.)

I've cloned the SVN repository and now have a Git repository with the SVN data.

I can associate Eclipse with the git repository but I don't know how to import the source code with my git workspace.

My question is how to set up Eclipse so that I have a git workspace that looks at my code and track it in my git repository. I can't see the source code in the git repository and there is no project to import.

The projects are java built with ant.

Comment: I'm wondering if I actually managed to clone the entire project... I'm currently doing a "git fetch" to get everything.

Answer (score -1):

Don't exactly know whether it will be helpful to you, but I recently looked up a few things about migrating into git from svn and maybe these to articles are helpful to you too:

http://john.albin.net/git/convert-subversion-to-git

https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/migrating-overview/

Comment: Thanks for helping but I've already found those.. they didn't help.

Comment: I read your own comment with the "git fetch". Git fetch actually don't clones any files, it just checks whether there are updates and so on. Try using "git clone ..." or if you already cloned it "git pull ..." to update it.

Comment: But if I'm uncertain that the clone completed? I can't run git clone again. It already says it's tracking that repository. "git svn pull" doesn't seem to be a command. "git svn fetch" actually does something.

Comment: Yes for SVN it is actually "git svn fetch" to get new commits from the SVN.
But I don't actually know whether this will also apply the changes it to your git. I did a svn to git integration recently with the atlassian guide and used the provided migration scripts (sync-rebase and clean-git) which worked quite fine for me as I could work with git afterwards and had the complete SVN history in my "git log"